# Connect-mongo Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, connect-mongo

Before of write this question I was reading other ones about almost the same error but that questions are from 2013-2014, and the solutions doesn't work, I'm using ElementaryOS (Ubuntu 14.04).

I want to manage sessions on my nodejs app which will be uploaded to an OpenShift server, so after searching for session storage alternatives I found `connect-mongo` which as I read, stores the session on a mongodb collection. I am also using `express-sessions`, the thing is, when I run the app I got this error message:

```
hugo@HugoG405:~/Documents/ic/server$ node server
module.js:341
   throw err;
   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hugo/Documents/ic/server/node_modules/express-sessions/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/objectid.js:8:16)
   at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hugo/Documents/ic/server/node_modules/express-sessions/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/objectid.js:18:16)
   at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
```

I'm new with sessions and storage them, so I really don't know what is happening and how correctly set up my session storage. I really need some help, I'll be so thankful if somebody can tell me how to fix this.
Here are my `package.json` dependencies:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.6.0",
    "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.1.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-sessions": "^1.0.5",
    "helmet": "^1.3.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.12",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-alpha6"
  },
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-image": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3"
  }
```

And here's my `configurate.js` file, which setup the middlewares, routes and db connections:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    helmet = require('helmet'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    sessions = require('express-sessions'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo/es5')(sessions);

// Rutas de la plataforma
var toHome = require('./routes/Home'),
    toVideos = require('./routes/Video'),
    toUsers = require('./routes/User'),
    toCourses = require('./routes/Course'),
    toRedirects = require('./routes/Redirects');

var connection_string = '127.0.0.1:27017/e3';
    if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
      connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
      process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
      process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
      process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
      process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
    }

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://"+connection_string);

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', function(){
        console.error.bind(console, 'Conection error to db:');
    });
    db.on('open', function() {
        console.log('Conected to mongodb');
    });

module.exports = function(app){
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(helmet());
    app.set('view engine','pug');

    app.use(sessions({
        secret:"23Ir892UdRHoi1rN891",
        resave:false,
        saveUninitialized:false,
        store: new MongoStore({
            url:connection_string,
            ttl: 24 * 60 * 60
        })
    }));


    // Routing
    app.use('/',toRedirects);
    app.use('/platform',toHome);
    //app.use('/platform/video',toVideos);
    //app.use('/platform/profile', toUsers);
    //app.use('/platform/course', toCourses);
}
```

And my `server.js` file if you need it:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    models = require('./config/models'),
    Configure = require('./config/configure');

Configure(app);

// Página principal
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});


var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';

app.listen(server_port,server_ip_address);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you didn't installed this module.

```
npm install connect-mongodb-session --save
```

This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please follow below steps to re install node modules.

- npm install node-gyp -g
- npm cache clean
- rm -rf node_modules
- npm install

Let us know if its work for you.